# Custom Menu change option menu in different fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments, menu

Fragment with Custom  menu : 
can I fragment change how to menu change ?Fragment B is equals like above with different inflate `XML` menu Menu work `ImageView` `menuView` `onClick` 
and fragment change change menu list name

```
public class BizForumFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener{
private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";
private String mParam1;
private String mParam2;
ImageView menuView;
Context context;
RequestParse requestParse;
PagerAdapter adapter;
ViewPager viewPager;

public BizForumFragment() {

}
public static BizForumFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
    BizForumFragment fragment = new BizForumFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
        mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
    }
    context = this.getContext();
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_biz_forum, container, false);
    viewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    adapter = new PagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager(), getContext());
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    menuView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.menuView);
    menuView.setOnClickListener(this);
    final TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    for (int i = 0; i < tabLayout.getTabCount(); i++) {
        TabLayout.Tab tab = tabLayout.getTabAt(i);
        tab.setCustomView(adapter.getTabView(i));
    }
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(getContext(), menuView);
    popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.article_menu, popup.getMenu());

    popup.show();
}

class PagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    String tabTitles[] = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.myLinks);
    Context context;

    public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Context context) {
        super(fm);
        this.context = context;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return tabTitles.length;
    }
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return new ArticlesFragment();
            case 1:
                return new DiscussionFragment();
            case 2:
                return new NewsFragment();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        // Generate title based on item position
        return tabTitles[position];
    }
    public View getTabView(int position) {
        View tab = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.tab_text_layout, null);
        TextView tv = (TextView) tab.findViewById(R.id.custom_text);
        tv.setText(tabTitles[position]);
        return tab;
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Previously, I had a similar problem. I announced in the class of fragments `updateToolbar()` method and called it in `ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener` for the selected fragment.
In the method `updateToolbar()` I called the following code:

```
getActivity().supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
```

After that occurred re-inflating of  menu resources.
You can find my example [here](https://github.com/OlafStaf/DroidFM/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/stafiiyevskyi/mlsdev/droidfm/view/fragment/ArtistContentDetailsFragment.java)